# Can I get Google Map description to show up when I embed a map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on a project where we're taking an [existing Google Map](http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msa=0&msid=200982308931784589810.000494b659528123b822c&ie=UTF8&t=m&source=embed&ll=43.199244,-70.904925&spn=0.04289,0.056262) and embedding it [on our page](http://dovertrail.wp.lamp.mandiasconsulting.com/maps/).  What we would like to do is pull the map description into the page and drop it into a div - but we can't find how to access the map description through the API. (Can you guess I'm new to Google Maps?)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The description is part of the KML feed of the map. You can either retrieve the KML feed as xml on the server, or combine it with a service like the google feed api to retrieve the result in javascript.